# Do you think a wallet could have value

Tags: wallet, value

Do you think a wallet could have value based solely on the 12 word phrase??

Do you think a wallet address with one of the twelve words being the word satoshi be considered a collectors item that has value?

I also have a wallet that has the same word twice so it’s a 11 word phrase lol I thought these we’re unquie and decided to hang onto them and see if anyone finds value in them.

I guess you couldn’t actually put your bitcoins in it because of fear Ide relog into it or could you or someone actually be able to block someone else from logging into a wallet if they got the 12 wordS? I think blockchain ip block would prevent a 12 word login

Comment: Do you think empty wallets with unique 12 word phrase be considered  Collectable like my satoshi

Answer (score 3):

No. The point of mnemonic seeds is to provide a human readable encoding for wallet backups.
To work as intended, they need to be unique and secret. Beyond that, anyone can just pick words from the [list](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#Wordlist) to create new seeds, so specific words appearing are not particularly interesting. Note that picking your words manually instead of randomly will severely reduce the security of the wallet.

Comment: Where is this list and how can I pick my own words

Comment: I've added the link to my answer.